# experiencing issues with position sticky CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two HTML pages, one that contains the navigation bar and the other contains some other content. I am using jQuery method $("#").load("nav.html"); to load the navbar into any other page for code reuse reasons. I'm applying the CSS property sticky to fix the navbar on the top of the page while scrolling down. This works fine when everything is contained into one page, but after factoring navbar code into nav.html, and loading it at the top of the other pages, it seems like the sticky property doesn't work anymore.

I know that the element with sticky property must have a parent element with greater height in order for it to work, which is the body tag in most cases. By looking at the page inspector on the browser it shows only one body tag, and everything from both HTML files contained within it as a single page, which seems correct. Since the hight of the body is obviously greater than the navbar. Can someone please give me an insight into what is happening, I am also using bootstrap 4.

```
<body>
<!---nabar.html gets loaded into this tag from index.html file-->
<div id="navigation-code"></div>

</body>
....

<!---this is the head of the nav bar container from nav.html file--->
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark py-0 sticky-top" role="navigation" style="background: black;">
....
</nav>
....
<body/>
```

Comment: Use 'position: fixed;' instead of 'position: sticky'. Sticky CSS will not support in IE browser.

Comment: try removing `<body>` from the nav.html file and then check

Comment: I tried doing that, but it seems like the browser still interprets the body tag as one